# family of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ is normal or not

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, normal-families

Here, $A(\mathbb{D})$ represents the collection of all holomorphic functions on the unit disc.
Let $\{f \in A(\mathbb{D}): f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n , |a_n| \leq 1, \: \forall n \geq 1 \}$.
Does the family normal or not?

If we can prove that the family is locally uniformly bounded, then by Montel theorem is normal family. These functions can be represented as power series at origin, so we conclude that

$|f(z)| \leq |f(0)| + \frac{r}{1-r}$, for all $z \in D(0,r)$ for some $r <1$.

This does not show the locally uniformly bounded for the family. But can I say that the family is not locally uniformly convergent and so it is not normal family? or it is insufficient work.

Comment: it depends on what defintion you use for a normal family - if you allow uniform divergence to infinity which is usually the case, then the family is normal (pick a sequence $f_n, f_n(0)=b_n$; if $|b_n| \to \infty$ then $f_n$ diverges to infinity uniformly on any compact set since $|f_n(z)| \geq |b_n| - \frac{r}{1-r}, |z| \le r<1$; if $|b_n|$ has a bounded subequence, said subsequence is then locally uniformly bounded so it has a convergent sub-subsequence), otherwise just take $f_n(z)=n$ which satisfies the hypothesis and obviously diverges uniformly to infinity on any compact set

Comment: @Conrad. How can I find a convergent sequence (excluding the infinity) satisfies the hypothesis but every subsequence is divergent?

Comment: not sure what is the question - $f_n(z)=n$ is a valid sequence which diverges compactly to infinity, so any subsequence does; if a sequence has $|f_n(0)|$ uniformly bounded it will be locally uniformly bounded (hence normal in the restricted sense) by the formula above, so all depends on how $|f_n(0)|$ behaves; overall the family is normal in the extended definition sense but not in the restricted definition sense, so that's why the answer to this questions hinges on which definition you use